# How to automatically switch to backup outlet if power goes away?

Tags: relay, outlet, redundancy

So I have two 220V outlets side by side. One of them has power all the time, the other is unreliable but has cheaper power. I'd like a device that uses the unreliable when power is present but switches to the normal when it's not. What is this called?

- Maybe some kind of failover switch I could just buy?
- Relay switch cotrolled by a Raspberry Pi via GPIO?
- UPS with dual power inputs?

Load is ~1700w and it's not a problem if the failover happens in an interrupted way. I would prefer something inexpensive.

Comment: Apart from the fact that a RPi is a huge overkill for such a device (if not too slow anyway), these sorts of devices are often used in server rooms for devices that have only a single PSU, but need to benefit from 2 phases in case of a power outage.  I suggest some Google-fu "automatic power redundancy switch" as this question is not a good fit for this site. Coming to think of it, it is probably called a RELAY.

Comment: The term you're looking for is automatic power transfer switch.  If either of the outlets are connected to the grid you should have it installed by a professional.

Comment: Note that the main component is a break before make safety contactor, so if your loads can't stand short interruption you may also need a UPS.

Comment: It is called an Automatic Transfer Switch (ATS).

Comment: Maybe you are looking for AUTOMATIC CHANGEOVER SWITCH also known as ACCL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT42VN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A relay transfer switch with supply 1 priority.*

How it works:

- If supply is present on L1/N1 then RLY1 is energised and the load is powered from L1/N1.
- If supply is lost on L1/N1 then RLY1 is de-energised and the load is supplied from L2/N2.

The relay needs a 220/230 V coil and contacts capable of 10 A (a little safety margin).

This system would be quite suitable for a resistive load such as heaters or lamps.

With inductive loads - think of devices with coils such as motors and transformers - there is a problem. Inductance "tries to keep the current going" and this causes arcing on the contacts. The situation is much worse if the two supplies are significantly out of phase. In the worse case you might switch from one supply at peak positive to the other at peak negative and cause high currents to flow for some milliseconds. You'll need to assess whether you can tolerate this.

If you decide that it can then purchase a contactor (high power AC relay). Again 220/230 V coil, and changeover contacts rated at 20 to 30 A should give you good reliability. This is most likely to be a 3-phase device (three contacts) but you'll only use two.

Both supplies need to have the appropriate circuit-breaker protection.